# Show that if A is algebraic closure of F and K is an intermediate field, then A is also the algebraic closure of K. Confirm solution?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I said if A is algebraic closure of F, then A is by definition algebraically closed and algebraic over F. Now A is algebraically closed over K as algebraic closure is unaffected by a subfield. Also, A is algebraic over K as it is algebraic over F because any element in A solves a polynomial in F which is in K. Is my proof correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.